# Test for Localhost in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have a powershell script that calls `Get-WmiObject` with `-Credential`. However, this errors out if I am running it against the local machine:

`Get-WmiObject : User credentials cannot be used for local connections`

What is the proper way to add an if localhost logic to avoid this error? Or is there a better way?

Comment: How are you passing in the computername parameter?

Comment: @Christopher: By IP (10.x.x.x), don't have much control over that as an application runs it.

Answer (score 3):

You could always query the local IP through WMI and store it in $localIP and then match that against whatever address is currently next in your pipeline or array:

```
if ($localIP -eq $otherIP) { get-wmiobject without -credential }    
else { existing query }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap it in a try catch block with erroraction stop on the first command, it will trap the error and run the catch block without credentials.

```
Try
{
Get-WmiObject -Credential domain\user -ComputerName localhost -class Win32_BIOS -erroraction Stop
}
Catch
{
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName localhost -class Win32_BIOS
}
```

Comment: Does PS allow me to catch a particular Exception for the error I am getting?

Comment: If you know the .NET Exception class you can do it like this...

catch [System.Net.SomeWMIExceptionClass]
{

code goes here

}

Comment: I am wrong.  Per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097785/powershell-ioexception-try-catch-isnt-working and some testing I did, PowerShell wraps the exception so you cannot catch specific errors.